# Multiple SELECT on the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, join

I want to get data both from atbv_Sales_Orders and atbv_Sales_prds views. As a result, I need to join those views on Domain and ProductID fields. Despite that I also want to create alias "Total" for Quantity field (from  atbv_Sales_prds view).

I've tried using `WHERE EXISTS` but I failed.

So I need to add ProductName and Supplier from atbv_Sales_prds. My currently written code: ( only with 1 select ).

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.Domain, p.OrderID, p.ProductID, p.Amount, p.Value,
p.PrimKey, p.Created, p.CreatedBy
FROM atbv_Sales_Orders p
  JOIN atbv_Sales_prds pv
    ON p.Domain = pv.Domain
  JOIN atbv_Sales_prds v
    ON pv.ProductID = v.ProductID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution for joining your tables, if I understood your problem:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.Domain, p.OrderID, p.ProductID, p.Amount, p.Value,
                p.PrimKey, p.Created, p.CreatedBy, pv.Quantity as Total
FROM atbv_Sales_Orders p
     JOIN atbv_Sales_prds pv
       ON p.Domain = pv.Domain AND pv.ProductID = v.ProductID
```

Comment: Thank you. Any Idea when I add to SELECT pv.Quantity as Total , rows start multiplying?

Comment: Adding pv.Quantity as Total should not change the number of rows, only add a new colum to the result, but maintain the same number of rows. Perhaps you could modify your question adding some details on the tables.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure  what you meant by "Total" alias but here's my take on this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.Domain, p.OrderID, p.ProductID, p.Amount, p.Value,
                pv.ProductName as ProductName, pv.Supplier as Supplier,
                p.PrimKey, p.Created, p.CreatedBy, pv.Quantity as Total
FROM atbv_Sales_Orders p
JOIN atbv_Sales_prds pv 
  ON p.Domain = pv.Domain AND pv.ProductID = v.ProductID
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to `SUM()` all quanitites, but this is not really clear. You have answers for the other options already though.

```
SELECT   p.Domain, p.OrderID, p.ProductID, p.Amount, p.Value,
         p.PrimKey, p.Created, p.CreatedBy, pv.ProductName,  
         pv.Supplier, SUM(pv.Quantity) AS Total
FROM     atbv_Sales_Orders p
JOIN     atbv_Sales_prds pv
ON       p.Domain = pv.Domain AND v.ProductID = pv.ProductID
GROUP BY p.Domain, p.OrderID, p.ProductID, p.Amount, p.Value,
         p.PrimKey, p.Created, p.CreatedBy, pv.ProductName, pv.Supplier
```